# SimCity (2013) not loading

Tags: simcity-2013, macos, origin

I have a Mac with the correct requirements and I have played the new SimCity before on it.

Now that I've updated my system to Mavericks and updated SimCity, it no longer loads.

When I click Play in Origin, it just sits there bouncing on my dock until it disappears (closing itself).

After reinstalling Origin and reinstalling SimCity, the same thing happens.

Any ideas why this is happening?